# Is there a name for a sub-sigma-algebra that contains all null sets?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, terminology

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ be a sub-sigma-algebra. Suppose that $\mathcal{B}$ has the following property.

> Every null set of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. every $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)=0$, is in $\mathcal{B}$.

Does this property have a name?
(Note that we are not requiring that $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is complete.)

Comment: As you wrote, we can take $\mathcal{B}= \mathcal{A}$. Do you mean to require $\mathcal{B}$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that every null set of $\mathcal{A}$ is in $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: I think he means ... Some sub-sigma-algebras $\mathcal B$ have this property, and others do not.  Is there a name for the ones that do?